# How to search product with SKU in shopify using PHP cURL

Tags: api, shopify

I want to search product with SKU number using php cURL.
For ex: https://{secret kay}:{password}@{store:URL}/admin/api/{api-version}/products/search.json?query=sku:{sku}

Answer (score 0):

The API you shared is correct, please use the code below to fetch the product based on SKU.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://yourstore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/products/search.json?query=sku:ABC74357',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET'
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

If you are using Linux, you must install the Apache server and PHP to run the above code, and for windows, you have to use the Xampp server.